# Unable to turn off Bluetooth in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

My Laptop got upgraded to Windows 10 yesterday. Since then, I can't turn off the Bluetooth. Clicking the Bluetooth icon in the Action center opens the PC settings.
There it's searching for other devices but I could not find the ON/OFF toggle button which was present in Windows 8.1. I have a Dell vostro 2520.

**EDIT**

I reinstalled the bluetooth driver and I can disable it from PC settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled my Wireless driver (includes both WiFi and Bluetooth). After reboot, the toggle button was there.

Answer (score 0):

### Do it in PC Settings

1. Under PC Settings -> Devices, find "Bluetooth"
2. You should be able to disable it from there

[image]

---

### Disable the adapter

1. Right click on your Network Icon and click "**Open Network & Sharing Center**"

[image]

2. On the left, click "**Change Adapter Settings**"

[image]

3. Right click on the Bluetooth connection and click "**Disable**"

[image]

---

(**Optional**) You can also access adapter settings from the Network & Internet section of PC Settings on Windows 10:

[image]

---

### If nothing worked

[In this question](https://superuser.com/questions/946581/option-to-turn-bluetooth-on-or-off-is-missing), people recommend doing the following before attempting to disable:

Update your driver

> 1. Bring up the start menu. Search for "**Device Manager**".
> 2. In Device Manager, expand Bluetooth.
> 3. Right click on Bluetooth Generic Adapter and update the driver.
> 4. Restart.

Uninstall software

> 1. Uninstall everything that is Bluetooth-related that is listed in Programs & Features.
> 2. Uninstall all Bluetooth-related drivers listed in the Device Manager.
> 3. Restart the computer. Bluetooth will be reinstalled, and you can reinstall the programs that you removed from Programs & Features.

Comment: But what happened to the toggle button which was present in Windows 8.1?

Comment: Honestly, who knows. I've noticed myself fundamental feature removals in Windows 10. Example, you used to be able to simply right click on any WiFi connection and choose 'properties'. You now have to jump through hoops. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work. Is there some other way to disable the bluetooth?

Comment: What doesn't work? Please be detailed. I updated my answer also with how to do it in PC settings.

Comment: I disabled the bluetooth device in network and sharing center but notification center says it's still on

Comment: Interesting, seems you aren't alone. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am on a PC without bluetooth, I think it's bugged since it says it's enabled and none of the suggestions above are even possible since there is no bluetooth settings.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).