# Bluetooth device missing

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, acer-aspire

Today I tried using my bluetooth and realized it was missing.

I went to my "**Devices Manager**" and it wasn't showing any Bluetooth devices.

However, following the instrucions [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/946581/option-to-turn-bluetooth-on-or-off-is-missing), I enabled "**Show hidden icons**" and it was listed. As there wasn't any "**Bluetooth Generic Adapter**", I followed the accepted answer on that same question, and uninstalled all Bluetooth drivers of my "**Device Manager**".

When I restarted it didn't try to reinstall any drivers, so I went myself to Acer site and got Bluetooth drivers.

I installed it, restarted, but the problem remains and it's worse, as **no bluetooth devices are shown in Device Manager**.

If I click again in the driver installer, it shows the options "Repair", "Alter" and "Delete" as if it was already installed.

I also installed "**Driver Talent**" and it shows no problems with my "**Bluetooth USB Device**", but of course there is a problem, since my Bluetooth disappeared together with its devices.

It is a new computer, just a couple of months. However I bought it in another country, so I can't use it's warranty....